# Auto refreshing when clicking a button

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when developing an example application on React.js When I click a  automatically refresh the whole page, so I cannot see (only by debugging) if the button is executing the method.

I share with you both components I've developed

**AForm component**

```js
import MyButton from '../Button/MyButton.jsx';


function AForm(){   

    const saludar = () =>{

        console.log("Hello World!!");   
       
        
    }

    return(

        <div>
            <form>
                <h2 className="text-center"> A Form</h2>
                <MyButton name={"Something"} onClickHandler={saludar}></MyButton>               
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AForm;
```

**My Button Component**

```
function MyButton({name,onClickHandler}){
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() =>onClickHandler()}>{name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyButton;
```

I've tried adding `return false` to the const but it stills refreshing the whole page

Comment: looks like your button is submitting the form. try to set type='button' on a button component (default is 'submit'). But not sure why you even have the <form>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the type is not mentioned for button so button inside form is acting as `type="submit"` button. That's why on click of button form is getting submitted.

Adding type="button" attribute to button will fix it.

```
function MyButton({name, onClickHandler}){
    return(
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => onClickHandler()}>{name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyButton;
```

Also this can be achived by `preventDefault()`

**AForm Component**

```
import MyButton from '../Button/MyButton.jsx';

function AForm(){   
    const saludar = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Hello World!!");
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <h2 className="text-center"> A Form</h2>
                <MyButton name={"Something"} onClickHandler={saludar}></MyButton>               
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AForm;
```

**My Button Component**

Gentle suggestion, include arrow function only when it's necessary.
If you're not passing any arguments then `onClick={(e) => onClickHandler(e)}` can also be written as `onClick={onClickHandler}`

```
function MyButton({name, onClickHandler}){
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClickHandler}>{name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyButton;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I put type="button" and it stopped. Thank you also for your suggestion. Right now I'm changing it

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you click the button in form, the form is being submited which is causing the page refresh. To aviod that add this to your function:

```js
const saludar = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Hello World!!");   
    }
```

`preventDefault` basicly means: Prevent the browser from its default behavior (which in this case is submiting a form and refreshing a page). Hope it makes sense.